# How to say "unmaintained", speaking about abandonware?

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german, software

I want to say that a given application is unmaintained:

- No support,
- No new features will ever be added,
- Bugs will not be fixed.

Can I say "nicht erhaltet"?

Preferably a short adjective so that it fits in this list:

```
* AnkiWeb (als Online-Version)
* AnkiMini (nicht erhaltet)
* AnkiMobile (kostenpflichtig)
* AnkiDroid (Open Source)
```

Comment: It should be noted that [abandonware](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware) is usually used to mean software that can no longer be acquired in a legal way (because the owner/producer no longer sells it). If you still give it away, but don't provide any support then I'd suggest you avoid that term.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: The English article lists 5 types, I am in the 5th one: "Open source and freeware programs that have been abandoned: In some cases, source code remains available, which can prove a historical artifact."

Comment: I see, my bad. Actually I've never heard that term used that way, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you describe sounds like the development of the software was ceased. I would use terms like "wird nicht mehr weiterentwickelt" or "Entwicklung eingestellt".

> AnkMini (Entwicklung eingestellt)

Comment: Das trifft es meines Erachtens am besten. Auch wenn die anderen Übersetzungen durchaus denkbar und vielleicht wortwörtlicher sind. +1

Answer (score 5):

Software maintenance is expressed as *"[Unterstützung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unterstuetzung)"* or sometimes "[*Pflege/pflegen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pflege)" in German. You could therefore say:

> AnkiMini (ohne Unterstützung)

However far more common is to use *"[Support](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Support)"* as this is a well established loanword from English:

> AnkiMini (kein Support)

Support in the general meaning would include help, bugfixes, and upgrades.

Answer (score 4):

*to maintain software* could be translated as *Software pflegen*, but it can't be simply negated, as *ungepflegt* has the connotation of *scruffy*.

*ungewartet* goes in the general direction, but doesn't really hit the spot.

Probably the closest translation would be *nicht betreut*.

Comment: Imho *[ungewartet](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/ungewartet)* doesn't really exists (not yet). (And only a few hits on google.) What about *nicht gewartet* (e.g. LEO propose that)?

Comment: Yes, sounds better.

Comment: "wird nicht weiter gepflegt" ginge aber.

Answer (score 1):

The - imho - best answer has Takkat already given (*ohne/kein Support*), but another possibility is:

> AnkiMini (ohne Wartung)

*Support* combined with *Software* is much more common than *Wartung* ([875 mio Hits](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=support%20software&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=pDd&rls=de&channel=suggest&q=%22support%22%20%22software%22&oq=%22support%22%20%22software%22&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v2&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i15l2.48442l50267l0l50511l4l4l0l0l0l0l160l314l3j1l4l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=78e2241e4baf3b7&biw=1680&bih=900) vs [13 mio Hits](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=wartung%20software&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=4Dd&rls=de&channel=suggest&q=%22wartung%22%20%22software%22&oq=%22wartung%22%20%22software%22&aq=f&aqi=g-l4&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i13l4.89487l92105l0l92223l4l4l0l0l0l0l174l481l2j2l4l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=78e2241e4baf3b7&biw=1680&bih=900)), but *Softwarewartung* express exactly what you are looking for:

> Unter Softwarewartung werden all jene Tätigkeiten verstanden, die nach der Einführung eines Softwaresystems dessen Verfügbarkeit und Nutzbarkeit sicherstellen oder die Lebensdauer der Software verlängern. Neben der Fehlerbehebung gehören die Funktionserhaltung und die Funktionserweiterung ebenso dazu wie perfektionierende Maßnahmen (z. B. Performanceverbesserung). <sup>[SOURCE](http://www.enzyklopaedie-der-wirtschaftsinformatik.de/wi-enzyklopaedie/lexikon/is-management/Systementwicklung/Hauptaktivitaten-der-Systementwicklung/Software-Wartung)</sup>